# SharePoint Workflow to create pdf from list columns and attach to Mail

Tags: workflow, list-item, pdf, document-template, word-automation

I need to generate a PDF from a newly created list item, and send an Email with this PDF attached. This task needs to be initiated at the server (Workflow/Service/PowerShell/etc).

What is the best way to to it?

thanks

EDIT:  SharePoint 2013

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using?

Comment: Sharepoint 2013

Answer (score 2):

OOTB SharePoint workflow doesn't have an option to convert your list item to PDF. To create PDF from your list item refer the below link,

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31695.sharepoint-2013-generating-a-pdf-document.aspx

But SharePoint designer workflow doesn't have an option to send email with attachment. So as you are using SharePoint 2013. You could create an item receiver in your list, on item create you can construct the PDF and send mail.

This is a third party solution, kindly check this,

http://www.muhimbi.com/landing/muhimbi-pdf-converter-for-sharepoint/muhimbi-pdf-converter-for-sharepoint.html?gclid=CjwKCAiA-P7xBRAvEiwAow-VaQnWMSNd-CLZDKpARPeOzQVnlEjYDjtlola12Ee0fnuJ64lQbjQ2JhoCi0oQAvD_BwE

Comment: If you find my answer helpful, kindly upvote and mark it as answer, so that it will be helpful for others too in future.